# Constructing a char pointer array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm having trouble below putting the input from getchar() into a char *arr[] array. The reason I'm doing this is because the input data, which will be a file with command line arguments, will be stored in an char pointer array to be passed to the execvp function.

I'm using getchar() is so I can later implement a feature which allows the user to press the 'tab' button and try and match a file to the text already typed.

After executing the below program, I type:
   ls -a    (with a trailing space)

which should obviously run but doesn't, I get a SEG 11 fault. If anyone could point what I'm doing wrong that would be really good!!

Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    char *arr[10];
    int l_count = 0, w_count = 0;
    char c;
    char *curLine;
    curLine = (char*)calloc(10, sizeof(char));
    while((c=getchar()) != '\n'){
        if (isspace(c)){
            curLine[l_count]='\0';
            memcpy(arr[w_count],curLine,strlen(curLine));           
            ++w_count;
            l_count=0;
        }       
        else{
            curLine[l_count]=c;
            ++l_count;
        }
    }
    arr[w_count]='\0';

    // Testing
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<2;i++){
        printf("%s, ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to allocate a new read buffer for each iteration through the loop. No memcpy() should be required for this, though a `realloc()` strategy may be warranted if you reach your allocation limit without hitting some space or EOF. Your "finished" detection should *assign* (not memcpy) the allocated string pointer to the next slot in `arr`, then start over with a newly allocated buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you want this:

```
int main(){
    char *arr[10];
    int l_count = 0, w_count = 0;
    char c;
    char *curLine;

    curLine = (char*)calloc(10, sizeof(char));

    while (1)
    {
        c = getchar() ;
        if (isspace(c)){
            curLine[l_count]='\0';
            arr[w_count] = curLine ;
            ++w_count;
            l_count=0;
            curLine = calloc(10, sizeof(char));
            if (c == '\n')
              break ;
        }       
        else{
            curLine[l_count]=c;
            ++l_count;
        }
    }

    // Testing
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < w_count; i++){
        printf("%s, ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // free memory
    for (i = 0; i < w_count; i++){
        free(arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here we also free the memory at the end, which is good practice, even if the program ends there anyway.

This program works, even if there is still more checking to be done, for example if you enter a word with more than 9 characters it will overflow the memory allocated by `calloc` and if you enter more than 10 words il will overflow the `arr` array which has a length of 10.

BTW in C you don't cast the return value of `calloc`, `malloc` and `realloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters you have not allocated any space in arr for the memcpy so this line
    memcpy(arr[w_count],curLine,strlen(curLine));
is copying yout curLine to a random location in memory. Similarly for all usage of arr later on.